# Hosting a private repo, can't find over http(s)

Tags: git

I am in the process of attempting to set up a local repo in our local network, so that I can keep remote computers in sync with one another and manage them remotely.
The way I set out to achieve this is by creating a private repo in our local intranet. I have a server set up running Centos 7, with Nginx, git, and PHP-FPM (although I guess this doesn't really need that, but it's there regardless).

I have Nginx up no problem. I go to the main URL for the local hostname and it loads up properly, with HTTPS.

My problem now, is when I try to run `git clone https://computer.example.com/git/repo.git`, it returns an error: `fatal: repository https://computer.example.com/git/repo.git/ not found`

I can't figure out how to properly get this to work. I don't need to push updates to it using https (although it would make it a lot easier).

Before anyone mentions, no there aren't any other alternatives. I'm doing this with minimal to no software installation, and behind a firewall. No internet access or anything else.

Here's my Nginx site config:

```
listen      443 ssl http2;
listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name  computer.example.com;

ssl                 on;
ssl_certificate     /home/it/ssl/example.com/certs/STAR_example_com.bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /home/it/ssl/example.com/csrs/ca-decrypted.key;


root   /home/it/sites/computer.example.com/public_html;

location ~ /git(/.*) {
    if ($arg_service = git-receive-pack) {
        rewrite /git(/.*) /git_write$1 last;
    }

    if ($uri ~ ^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$) {
        rewrite /git(/.*) /git_write$1 last;
    }

    if ($arg_service = git-upload-pack) {
        rewrite /git(/.*) /git_read$1 last;
    }

    if ($uri ~ ^/git/.*/git-upload-pack$) {
        rewrite /git(/.*) /git_read$1 last;
    }
}

location ~ /git_read(/.*) {
    include git-http-backend.conf;
    fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/it/sites/computer.example.com/public_html/git;
}

location ~ /git_write(/.*) {
    auth_basic "Pushing to Git repositories is restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    include git-http-backend.conf;
    fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/it/sites/computer.example.com/public_html/git;
}


# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}

# deny access to .ini files
#
location ~ \.ini$ {
    deny  all;
}
```

git-http-backend.conf:

```
# /etc/nginx/git-http-backend.conf 
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/it.sock;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
```

php-fpm.d/it.conf: (if needed)

```
[it]
user = it
group = it
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/it.sock
listen.owner = it
listen.group = it
listen.mode = 0660
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = passthru,shell_exec,system
;php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
chdir = /
```

Granted I know some parts aren't needed, I just left them there. If they do cause for concern though, let me know. I can work around them.

This is what resides in the repo.git directory:

```
branches/
config
description
HEAD
hooks/
info/
objects/
refs/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "the main URL for the local hostname" mean? You tested connectivity from the server itself? What about the git command - are you running that on the same server you tested regular web connectivity, or somewhere else?

Comment: I just meant the domain pointing to that computer. In this example's case, I substituted it for computer.example.com. It's in a domain network, so every device is a subdomain internally basically. Yes, I can reach the computer from mine, and I am using the same computer to attempt the clone.

Comment: So is the "local hostname" you entered in your browser, the same as the hostname in your git URI?

Comment: Yes. If I go to https://computer.example.com on my browser, nginx comes up with the index. Going to https://computer.example.com/git/repo.git/ shows the files/folders in that directory, same as in the server itself. CLoning the same URL, with and without the trailing slash returns the "fatal: repo not found" response.